# Find a matrix for the linear transformation of reflection about a $\theta$ line using the matrix for projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, reflection

Projection matrix:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos^2\theta & \cos\theta \sin\theta\\
        \cos\theta \sin\theta & \sin^2\theta\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Reflection matrix:
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2\cos^2\theta -1 & 2\cos\theta sin\theta\\
        2\cos\theta \sin\theta & 2\sin^2\theta -1\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos2\theta & \sin2\theta\\
        \sin2\theta & -\cos2\theta\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
I can arrive at the second form geometrically, but the problem asks that I do it with the projection matrix and vector addition. Any hints/tips?

It could also be that the problem is poorly worded, in which case a geometrical analysis is all that is necessary.

> Find a formula for $R$ based on $P$. Explain your arguments by drawing a
>   graph, using the rules of sums of vectors.

I drew the graph and was able to successfully explain it in terms of sums of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

use this fact: if $X$ is a point, $X'$ its projection on the axis and $X''$ the reflection of $X$, than $X'$ is the middle point of $XX''$.

---

so, if $P$ is the projection matrix and $R$ the reflection, we have:

$$
X'=PX \qquad X''=RX 
$$
and, we write the fact that $X'$ is the midpoint as:
$$
X+X''=2X'
$$

so:

$$
X+RX=2PX \quad \Rightarrow \quad RX=2PX-X=(2P-I)X
$$

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense that the reflection is a projection onto the $\theta$ line, then another projection onto another $\theta$ line, but there's something missing. My textbook highlights it as $2P-I$, but it has no explanation for why the I pops up.

Comment: I've added to my answer. I hope it's useful.